# php html checkboxes error

Tags: php, html

Can anyone tell my why part of my code is not displaying?

Here is my HTML form:

```
<form action="OrderOutput.php" method="Post">
<fieldset>
<legend>Select a Crust</legend> 
<table> 

<tr> 
<td>
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Thin">Thin
</td>   
<td> 
$1.00 
</td>  
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Medium">Medium
</td> 
<td>  
$2.00
</td>  
</tr> 

<tr>
<td> 
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Thick">Thick
</td> 
<td> 
$3.00
</td> 
</tr>
</table>
</fieldset> 


<fieldset>
<legend>Select Toppings</legend> 


<table>  
<tr> 
<td> 
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Mushrooms">Mushrooms
</td> 
<td> 
$4.00
</td>
</tr> 


<tr> 
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Pepperoni">Pepperoni
</td> 
<td> 
$5.00
</td> 
</tr> 
</table>
</fieldset> 
<input type="submit" name="checkout" value="Checkout"> 

</form>
```

When I send the values to my php page, it only displays this line:

```
$selected_crust = $_POST['choice'];   

echo "Your selections: Crust: $selected_crust";
```

but not this:

```
foreach ($_POST['check'] as $selected_toppings) { 
echo "Toppings: $selected_toppings ";
}
```

Is there something wrong with my html checkboxes that is causing the information to not display in php?

Comment: change your names to choice1, choice2 and choice3 and try again (And check $_POST['choice1'] etc

Comment: Works for me as is. What happens for you? Is this all the code? Is it erring or just not displaying the toppings?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that @user3791775. Can you do a `print_r($_POST)` and post what you see? Are you checking a box before you submit?

Comment: The toppings aren't displaying. That's my only problem

Comment: comment out the block of code that is giving you the issue and add `print_r($_POST['check'])` what does it show?

Comment: Yes Tony, I would even have said `print_r($_POST);` for OP comprehension

Comment: `name="choice"` needs to be `name="choice[]"`

Comment: This is what I got when i checked both mushrooms and pepperoni: Array ( [0] => Mushrooms [1] => Pepperoni )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working correctly, you just need to catch if a user has submitted no checkboxes:

```
if ( isset($_POST['check']) && is_array($_POST['check']) )
{
    //If you want to just show toppings once, a simple implode will work:
    //echo "Toppings: ", implode(', ', $selected_toppings);

    foreach ($_POST['check'] as $selected_toppings) { 
       echo "Toppings: $selected_toppings ";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Toppings: You didn't select any!";
}
```

Comment: what do I change if I don't want to use a foreach loop though? I don't want to display the toppings twice if both are chosen

Comment: I posted a comment (Above the foreach loop)